# ManyToOne cascade not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework

In Play Framework! I defined two models :

On one hand,

```
@Entity
public class DashboardPosition extends Model  {
    public int orderId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Dashboard dashboard;
}
```

And on the other hand,

```
@Entity
public class Dashboard extends Model  {
    ...
}
```

For some reason, when deleting a dashboard via "dashboard.delete()" I get an error with the following log.

```
12:07:20,190 DEBUG ~ delete from Dashboard where id=?
12:07:20,204 WARN  ~ SQL Error: 23003, SQLState: 23003
12:07:20,204 ERROR ~ Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKF7C253BD5A49DA96: PUBLIC.DASHBOARDPOSITION FOREIGN KEY(DASHBOARD_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.DASHBOARD(ID)"; SQL statement:
delete from Dashboard where id=? [23003-149]
12:07:20,204 WARN  ~ SQL Error: 23003, SQLState: 23003
12:07:20,204 ERROR ~ Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKF7C253BD5A49DA96: PUBLIC.DASHBOARDPOSITION FOREIGN KEY(DASHBOARD_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.DASHBOARD(ID)"; SQL statement:
delete from Dashboard where id=? [23003-149]
```

Which makes me think that cascade is not working in my case.
Any clue of why this might be happening / how to debug this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cascade is on the wrong side of the association.

You want all the dashboard's positions deleted when you delete a dashboard. But you don't want the dashboard deleted when you delete one of its positions. The cascade should thus be set on the `@OneToMany` annotation of the Dashboard's `positions` field.